# Jquery Need siblings value but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to populate the value of the "eventTitle" in "Requirement" input box when some one click on the corresponding check box. i.e If some one clieck on the check box of Vels Group Of Instutions then automatically i want this to populate in texbox with name "Requirement" if multiple check box are clicked i want it to be comma seperated. Below is the code i tried to get but it is not working and getting undefined.

```
    <div class="wid100">
    <div class="eventTitle">Vels Group Of Instutions</div>
    <div class="eventDate">2017-07-25</div>
    <div class="eventVenue">This is world wide institute of technology </div>
    <div class="selectEvent">
        <input type="checkbox" class="seminar selected" id="179">
        <label for="179"></label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wid100">
    <div class="eventTitle">Title goes here</div>
    <div class="eventDate">2017-07-25</div>
    <div class="eventVenue">sdfdsafasdfdsafdsafsadfsdfsdf </div>
    <div class="selectEvent">
        <input type="checkbox" class="seminar" id="179">
        <label for="179"></label>
    </div>
</div>


<input type="text" name="Requirement" placeholder="Title 01" id="divclass" required="required" class="pull-left" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

```js
$(".seminar").click(function () {

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

             //checked
             $(this).addClass("selected");
             var event_title = "";

              event_title =  $(".selected").siblings('.eventTitle').val();
              console.log(event_title); return false;

         } else {
             //unchecked
             $(this).removeClass("selected");
         }

});
```

Comment: `.eventTitle` is not the sibling of `.selected`. It is the sibling of its parent i.e. `.selectEvent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.eventTitle` is not the sibling of `.selected` and the .eventTitle is a div element having no value, text there. change this line

```
event_title =  $(".selected").siblings('.eventTitle').val();
```

to

```
event_title =  $(this).parent().siblings('.eventTitle').text();
```

or

```
event_title =  $(this).parent().siblings('.eventTitle').html();
```

Comment: RAUSHAN KUMAR Thank you so much this is working , one debut  parent text is coming  i need if unchecked means that parent text is remove how will write this one please help me.

Comment: How will pass the "event_title" text value to other input type text box "divclass"

Comment: to set the text of other div use `$('#divclass').val(eventNames);`

Comment: RAUSHAN KUMAR, This is working fine thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is because `.eventTitle` is not a sibling of the clicked checkbox, so the DOM traversal logic is wrong. `div` elements also do not have a `val()`, so you should use `text()` or `html()` instead.

*However*, you can improve the logic and also achieve the comma separated list of the selected event titles by using `map()` to build an array which you can then `join()` before setting in the value of `#divclass`. Try this:

```js
$(".seminar").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
  
  var eventNames = $('.seminar:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).closest('.wid100').find('.eventTitle').text();
  }).get().join(',');
  $('#divclass').val(eventNames);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wid100">
  <div class="eventTitle">Vels Group Of Instutions</div>
  <div class="eventDate">2017-07-25</div>
  <div class="eventVenue">This is world wide institute of technology </div>
  <div class="selectEvent">
    <input type="checkbox" class="seminar selected" id="179">
    <label for="179"></label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wid100">
  <div class="eventTitle">Title goes here</div>
  <div class="eventDate">2017-07-25</div>
  <div class="eventVenue">sdfdsafasdfdsafdsafsadfsdfsdf </div>
  <div class="selectEvent">
    <input type="checkbox" class="seminar" id="179">
    <label for="179"></label>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" name="Requirement" placeholder="Title 01" id="divclass" required="required" class="pull-left" size="100" />
```

I'd suggest changing the id of the `#divclass` to something more descriptive, as the element is not a `div`, and it's an identifier, not a class.

Finally, your `.seminar` elements have the same `id` attribute which is invalid. You should ensure that the ids are unique within the DOM - assuming that this is not just a typo from copy/pasting the code in the question.